# incompatibilidad entre laravel 7 y hyn/multi-tenant

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de instalar la biblioteca hyn/multi-tenant en laravel 7, ya que los requisitos asi lo indican. Pero me sale este error.
[image]
este es mi composer.json
[image]
si ha alguien ya le paso como lo solucionó? o es un error interno de la libreria?

Comment: Los mensajes de error son bastante claros.

Comment: entiendo que me piden remover un paquete, pero este es del core de laravel, lo cual no creo me daria mas problemas que soluciones

Answer (score 0):

coloque el issue en el github de la libreria y ya actualizaron ramsey a 4.0.0, problema resuelto.
https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant/issues/917